# Converting special characters in to string

Tags: android

Hi I'm trying to show the expression of a calculator as a text in a TextView in android. Once the buttons are clicked each pressed number needed to be shown in the textView. For an example,

if buttons 1,2,3 were pressed 123 needed to be shown. When 123+23 is pressed it needed to be displayed as it is.

So I coded it like this.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
        String value="";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        }

        public void buttonOnClick(View view){

            Button b = (Button)view;
            String buttonText = b.getText().toString();
            value=value+buttonText;

            TextView myTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            myTextView.setText(value);

        }
    }
```

But when charachers like *, / , + were entered though an expression like 123/250 needed to be displayed as it is, as a string it displays in the textView is looking like 250/123. What is the mistake I have done in the logic. Please kindly someone help. Why the "/" comes infront of 123.

Answer (score 0):

probably you have to parse your buttonText first to determine if it is a digit or otherwise.
if it is a digit, concatenate as usual
else, add additional space in front and behind the buttonText during the concatenation

Comment: Hi @user3789200, I tried out your code and it seems to be working actually.